# Phonegap localStorage not backing up to iTunes

Tags: javascript, html, ios, cordova, local-storage

So I'm building an app using Phonegap and have come across an issue in my ad hoc testing phase.
   After installing the app on my iDevices, I've tried to back up the data contained within localStorage to iTunes. For some reason, none of the things I've saved to localStorage seem to be retrieved when I re install the app. I've changed BackupWebStorage in my config file to "local" but that has not helped. 
   I know that ios 5.1 created many issues for localStorage being backed up and am wondering if that's still the case. If so, what would be my best alternative to localStorage? I'm content with using the File API or a local SQL database, I just need some direction before I rewrite a large amount of code.

Thanks!